# How to get all (parent) data and load their children data (eager load) but with condition on parent column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

let say I want to get all users and their posts only if user.status is true.

How to achieve this using eager loading (i.e with)

data I wanted to get:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "status": true,
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "comment": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "comment": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "comment": "abc"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from DB using Eloquent? If yes why not use simple `User::where('status', true)->with('posts)->get();`

Comment: please try to understand the question first

Comment: Explain it further. Your question has no proper explanation at all

Comment: Ok I get it sorry my bad you wanted to filter out the child relationship

Comment: does your answer retrieve the required result mentioned in q ?

Comment: No it does not I was thinking you wanted to filter that parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by loading all users, then filtering the ones you want to load, and finally eager load their relationship.

```php
$users = User::all();
$users->filter->status->load('posts');
```

Comment: is there anything wrong with this ? works like a charm for me

Comment: Yes. Loading all data and filtering them out on php end while you can use simple MySQL query to filter out the data is a bad practice and impacts the performance. You could have used simple `where` condition rather than using Collection functions which loops all the data retrieved,

Comment: My bad I was wrong. I didn't understand the question properly and I am not able to remove that downvote

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fairly modern version of Laravel, you may want to look at the documentation on API Resources:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

---

**Conditional Relationships** [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships)

Try something like this:

```
/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        ...
        'posts' => $this->when((bool) $this->status, PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts'))),
        ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Your way works, but you're not handling the eager loading

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, where I needed to use the `with` method to load related data, but I also wanted to filter it further, like using the `where` method. Unfortunately, the `with` method doesn't directly support such filtering.

So, the solution, I must say, is a little bit tricky. To work around this limitation, you can create a custom alias using the `selectRaw` method in your model and use this alias to establish the desired relation.

In your specific scenario, you can try the following code:

```
User::selectRaw('users.*, IF(status = FALSE, null, id) as idx')->with('post')->get()
```

This code creates an alias named `idx`. If the `status` of a user is `FALSE`, it sets `idx` to `null`, otherwise, it uses the `id`.

Next, you can define the relation like this in your User model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'idx');
}
```

This means that if the `users.status is FALSE`, `idx` will be `null`. On the other hand, if `users.status is TRUE`, `idx` will have the value of `id`. Consequently, the subsequent query for the posts table will utilize the idx as the related key.